# jquery navigation bar: submenus are not hidden on documentReady in jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle, navigationbar, document-ready

The following is my code: [navigation bar](http://jsfiddle.net/vaanipala/DhA2Z/2/)

This navigation bar works well on my computer - the submenus are hidden on document ready. However, on jsfiddle, i don't know on why the submenus are not hidden on document ready. Can someone point out on where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from the js segment `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>`

[fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/DhA2Z/6/)

Comment: yes jsfiddle works now. Thanks. Now, the problem is when I hover on #subsubmenu1 - onmouseover and onmouseout event handlers are not working smoothly. When i try to hover on the Company Price link, immediately #subsubmenu1 dissappears. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Take the script tags (both start and end) out of the script section of your jsFiddle and your code will run.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/DhA2Z/7/